# Error declaring and using signed complex quantity using enumerated indices

Tags: vhdl

I declared the following in a common package file called FAT_Lib:

```
type complex_field is (re,im);
type signed_complex is array(complex_field) of signed;
```

I then declared a signal in the port interface of an entity the following way:

```
MF: out signed_complex(9 downto 0);
```

Modelsim produces the following error when the entity is compiled:

> In array constraint at depth 1 the array fat_rtl.FAT_Lib.signed_complex has already been constrained.

I understand that the compiler takes the `(9 downto 0)` as constraining the array size rather than the signed quantity wordlength. Does anyone see the error(s) in my declaration? My goal is to be able to access the real and imaginary parts of `MF` as `MF(re)` and `MF(im)`.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a record? `MF.re` and `MF.im`...

Comment: Yes @J.H.Bonarius - with a record, VHDL-2008 is not required. The syntax for records with unconstrained fields can get a bit wild, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need VHDL 2008. You need something like this:

```
MF: out signed_complex_array(open)(9 downto 0);
```

where the `(open)` is used to skip over the *constrained* dimension.

Comment: See Peter Ashenden and Jim Lewis's book *VHDL 2008 Just the New Stuff* 3.1.2 Subtype Indications and Constraints *...In earlier versions of VHDL, the only kind of constraint we could apply to a composite subtype was an index constraint to specify index ranges for an otherwise unconstrained array type. All of the array elements and subelements of the array type had to be constrained. The situation is different in VHDL-2008, since we can have array and record types in which some element or subelement subtype is an array subtype without an index constraint....*

Answer (score 0):

Altera's Quartus 13.1 synthesizer had problems when I used records for complex quantities. Hence the slightly convoluted way of declaring complex quantities. I am using VHDL-2008.

I managed to fix the problem in my declaration the following way:

In common package:

```
type complex_field is (re,im);
type signed_complex is array(complex_field range <>) of signed;
```

In entity port interface:

```
MF: out signed_complex(re to im)(9 downto 0);
```

I tried Matthew Taylor's suggestion the following way and that worked as well.

```
type complex_field is (re,im);
type signed_complex is array(complex_field) of signed;

MF: out signed_complex(open)(9 downto 0);
```

Thanks for the comments.